# changes and approximations

Tags: calculus

The period $P$ of a pendulum of lenght $L$ is given by $P=2 \pi \sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{L}{g}}$, where $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.

a) Assuming that $L$ remains fixed, show that a $1$ % increase in $g$ results in approximately a $1/2$ % decrease in period $P$

b) For fixed $g$, what percentage change in $L$ will produce a $1$% increase in $P$

I use that $\Delta y=\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\Delta x$

So in a) I have $\Delta P=\displaystyle\frac{dP}{dg}\cdot\Delta g$

$\Delta P=-\displaystyle\frac{\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}}{g}\cdot\Delta g$

Hereafter I need help

Answer (score 1):

You did not take $\frac {dP}{dg}$ correctly. Note that $P$ goes as $g^{-1/2}$, so use the power rule.  But for fractional changes, it is better to take logs first, so $$\log P = \log(2\pi)+\frac 12\log L - \frac 12 \log g$$  Now take the differential, getting $$\frac {dP}P=\frac 12 \frac {dL}L-\frac 12 \frac {dg}g$$  These are in the form of fractional variation that you want.

Answer (score 0):

a)

In this case, note that:
$$P+\Delta P =2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g+\Delta g}}$$
And, as $g+\Delta g=1.01g$, we have:
$$P+\Delta P =2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{1.01g}}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1.01}}=\frac{P}{\sqrt{1.01}}\approx0.99503P$$
$$\Rightarrow \Delta P = -0.004962P$$

So the $1\%$ increase in $g$ produces a $0.5\%$ decrease in $P$.

I didn't use your method, because we don't know the initial conditions on $P,L,g$ to evaluate the derivative in 
$$\Delta P\approx \frac{dP}{dg}\Big|_{(P_0,L_0,g_0)}\Delta g$$

b) We want $\Delta P =1.01P$ for a given $x$ percentage in $L$, so

$$P+\Delta P =1.01P=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{(1+x)L}{g}}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}\sqrt{1+x}$$
So
$$1.01=\sqrt{1+x}\Rightarrow x=1.01^2-1=0.0201$$

So you need a $2.01\%$ increase in $L$ to get a $1\%$ increase in $P$.